# Jmesa with checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, jmesa

I have a jsp that shows a JMesa where one column is a checkbox type. I managed to make the checkbox header and that it selects all the options if checked. My problem is binding the checkbox of each row to each respective boolean of the element of the list. When I check some options and submit the data the booleans always show as false.

The list is made of objects A, which contains an object B and a boolean. I want that boolean to the true if the checkbox is checked.

Here is mi JMesa:

```
<jmesa:tableFacade
id="table_1"
items="${A}"
var="a"
toolbar="...CustomToolbar">
    <jmesa:htmlTable>
        <jmesa:htmlRow>

         .. columns showing attributes of B ..  

            <jmesa:htmlColumn headerEditor="...CheckboxHeaderEditor" filterable="false" sortable="false">
             <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="sendMail" name="sendMail" value="${a.sendMail}"/>
            </jmesa:htmlColumn> 
        </jmesa:htmlRow>
   </jmesa:htmlTable>
</jmesa:tableFacade>
```

What I want is to be able to choose from the list which objects B to send in an e-mail.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a "non-jmesa" workaround.

With javascript and assuming you have the row ids in the jmesa table: select all row ids with checked checkboxes and then create a comma-separated array of the ids (easier if you use jquery/dojo/similar). Finally, just submit the array to the server.

Hope it helps.